# Java date class interesting

Tags: java, date

End date was being computed to be earlier than the start date

```
Date startDate = new Date();
Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (24 * 3_600_000 * 42));
System.out.println(startDate);
System.out.println(endDate);
```

output :

```
Tue Sep 17 01:46:31 EEST 2013
Mon Sep 09 08:43:43 EEST 2013
```

why the output is not correct ?

Comment: `System.out.println(24 * 3600000 * 42);`

Comment: Thanks Oli it is calculated as negative number I disgraced myself :):)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your integer arithmetic has overflowed.  The maximum possible value of an `int` is [`2147483647` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE) (a little over 2 billion), but multiplying your integer literals would yield 3628800000 (about 3.6 billion).  The result is a negative number (`-666167296`), and an earlier date.

Try casting one of your literals as a `long` to force `long` arithmetic (or use `long` literals):

```
( (long) 24 * 3600000 * 42)
```

or

```
(24L * 3600000 * 42)
```

This operation is well within the range of `long` values (max value `9223372036854775807`, over 9 quintillion).

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by rgettman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18838676/642706) is specifically correct. More generally, you are using terribly flawed legacy classes that since your post were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

FYI, `java.util.Date` now replaced by [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

We can replace your code with the following.

```
Instant.now().plus( Duration.ofDays( 42 ) )
```

No need for your math.

The `java.time.Instant` class represents a moment, a point on the timeline, as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. This is the same meaning as the `java.util.Date` replaced by `Instant`.

The `Duration` class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline on the scale of hours-minute-seconds. If you want to represent your 42 days as forty-two chunks of 24-hour time rather than calendar days, use `Duration`.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
Duration fortyTwoGenericDays = Duration.ofDays( 42 ) ;
Instant fortyTwoGenericDaysLater = now.plus( fortyTwoGenericDays ) ;
```

To see the result of code above through the clock and calendar of a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`24 * 3600000 * 42` is `3,628,800,000` which does not fit into an `int`. Rollover occurs. Force the use of a long by casting one of the factors:

```
24L * 3600000 * 42
```

Answer (score 0):

The number you're trying to add is 24 * 3600000 * 42 which is equal to 3,628,800,000. This is larger than 2,147,483,647 which is the maximum value that can be represented with the given data type. What you're experiencing is an *overflow*, meaning that after crossing the maximum value, the number loops back to its lowest value, which is in the negative. Therefore, you're adding a *negative* value to the date.